# GO: Date and Time Parsing in GO

Tags: go

I have format string "day/month/year, hour:minute:second"

How do I parse into a time object?

I tried:

```
const longForm = "5/01/2015, 12:00:00"

t1, _ := time.Parse(longForm, "5/01/2015, 12:00:00") 

0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

I get some UTC time, but this is not helpful if I want to compare times because I get the same UTC time for them all. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule #1 of fightclub, err Go, check your errors.

That being said, the format for time parsing is defined in the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-overview) (scroll down to constants).

For your specific question, the format is `1/_2/2006, 15:04:05`.

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/E3w6Vm4Qei)

Comment: Thanks so much I was looking for the format. This is my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that means I have to switch day and month

Comment: ah, i thought it was the other way around for you.

Comment: "1/_2/2006, 15:04:05" would work